# KendoUI Validate Numeric Textbox

Tags: kendo-ui

The KendoUI validation does not work with kendo-numeric-textbox. I get the following error.
"An invalid form control with name='amount' is not focusable. "

See example below. Try submit and see error in browser console.

http://plnkr.co/edit/pXpXexPq3u9xAzzpKR8Y?p=preview

I´m trying to get required popup "Please fill out this field" with the Kendo numeric textbox.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be some strange issue with hidden fields using the **kendoNumericTextBox**.

I was able to get it to work using the kendo validator:  [[See here]](http://plnkr.co/edit/ysEYvAV4i11NWAzXCw49?p=preview)

There's also an interesting article [[Here]](http://blogs.visoftinc.com/2013/06/27/kendoui-numerictextbox-validation/)

**Updated Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {


   $("#amount").kendoNumericTextBox();


    var validator = $("#testForm").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator"), status = $(".status");
    $("form").submit(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    if (validator.validate()) {
                        status.text("Valid")
                            .removeClass("invalid")
                            .addClass("valid");
                    } else {
                        status.text("Not Valid")
                            .removeClass("valid")
                            .addClass("invalid");
                    }
                });

});
```